# javascript executing wrong function

Tags: javascript

I'm writing some client-side Javascript, where I want to render some tabs and a table. This is the relevant code:

```
(function() {

    var Table = function() {
        this.render = function() {
            console.log('rendering table');
        };
        return this;
    };

    var Tabs = function() {
        var table = Table();
        this.render = function() {
            console.log('rendering tabs');
            table.render();
        };
        return this;
    };

    (function() {
        var tabs = Tabs();
        tabs.render();
    })();

})();
```

What I expect: the console should show `rendering tabs`, `rendering table`, and be done with it.

What actually happens: the console shows thousands of `rendering tabs` until jsFiddle crashes.

This shows that `table.render()` actually calls `tabs.render()` recursively. But why? I found this behaviour quite puzzling, can somebody explain where my mistake is?

Comment: Use `new Tabs()` and `new Table()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is the way you are calling `Tabs`:

```
var tabs = new Tabs();
tabs.render();
```

And `Table`:

```
var table = new Table();
```

The reason for your issue is that `this` refers to the global object (`window`) when the function is not invoked with the `new` operator. The first thing `Tabs` does is call `Table`, and both set `this.render`. When invoked with `new` each will have its own context and therefore its own `render` method.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I now also added `"use strict";` to the top of my file to be warned of such problems.